# Is it possible to boost frequency in a programmable crystal oscillator?

Tags: oscillator

I have a programmable crystal oscillator [SG-8002](https://www5.epsondevice.com/en/products/crystal_oscillator/sg8002ca.html). Is it possible to boost frequency a little bit somehow?

Comment: Where's the link to the datasheet? Thank afterwards by upvoting useful answers and accepting the best one.

Comment: https://ru.mouser.com/datasheet/2/137/SG_8002JF_en-1649544.pdf

Comment: Just use the programmer and set your new frequency. They claim 1-125Mhz.

Comment: Well, it is a **programmable** crystal oscillator.  Have you searched on "programming the SG-8002"?

Comment: But you can program this crystal only once. Or not ?

Comment: That is a different question.

Comment: I'm thinking about boosting voltage.

Comment: Your comments make me think you need to share more about your usage scenario to get an answer that will help you.  What are you trying to do, and why?

Comment: My crystal's programmed 50 MHz. I need 50.5 MHz.

Comment: Can you use 101MHz then divide by two?

Comment: ROM chips can't change frequencies

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, if you buy the [programming tool](https://www5.epsondevice.com/en/products/crystal_oscillator/sgwriterii.html), the range is 1MHz to 125MHz for that specific part.

There are a few companies that do programmable oscillators some provide the programmers and some don't.

Comment: My oscillator's already been programmed. Can I program it once again?

Comment: I would try it, nothing in any of epsons documentation indicates if it is either a one time program or if the memory can be rewritten. The only thing they mention is that the part is 'writeable' and it has a 'prom'.

Comment: If it's a PROM, it's probably e-fuse which means you get only one try. If it were reprogrammable or multi-time programmable I think they'd mention that. SiTime has a line of programmable oscillators, here: https://www.sitime.com/products/lvcmos-oscillators/sit8008

Comment: That is my line of thinking also, and the fact that there is nothing about rewriting. On the flip side the programmable chips are for prototyping, and then they want you to order the specific frequency. That's why I say try it and see what happens